# Find the number of solutions of $\sin x+2 \sin 2x- \sin 3x=3$

Tags: trigonometry, trigonometric-series, inverse-function

In $(0 \:\:\pi)$Find the number of solutions of $$\sin x+2 \sin 2x- \sin 3x=3$$

The equation can be written as

$$\sin x+4 \sin x \cos x=3+\sin 3x$$ i.e.

$$\sin x(1+4\cos x)=3+\sin 3x$$ i.e.,

$$\sin x(1+4\cos x)=3+\sin x(3-4\sin^2 x)=3+\sin x(4\cos ^2x-1)$$  so

$$\sin x(4\cos^2 x-4\cos x-2)=-3$$ Any hint from here?

Comment: Let $f(x)=\sin x+2 \sin 2x-\sin 3x-3$, since you only need to know the number of solutions, by the continuity of $f(x)$ you can simply discuss when $f(x)>0$ and when $f(x)<0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One easily verifies that
$$f(x):=\sin x+2\sin(2x)-\sin(3x)=2\sin x\bigl(2\cos x-\cos(2x)\bigr)\ .$$
Since the function $h(x):=2\cos x-\cos(2x)$ assumes its maximum ${3\over2}$ at $x={\pi\over3}$ (check this!) one obtains
$$f(x)\leq2\sin x \cdot {3\over2}=3\qquad(0<x<\pi)\ ,$$
whereby equality cannot take place, since $h\bigl({\pi\over2}\bigr)<{3\over2}$.

The conclusion is that the given equation has no solutions in $\ ]0,\pi[\ $.

Answer (score 3):

Hint of one possible solution: (assume your derivation is correct)
$$4\cos^2x-4\cos x-2=(2\cos x-1)^2-3\ge -3$$
and on $(0,\pi)$ we have $0<\sin x\le 1$.
Thus the LHS of your last equation should be $\ge -3$ on $(0,\pi)$.
Then you only need to check when the equality is satisfied, which is simple.

Comment: Explain in detail what you are trying to do. Also wolfram says that this has no solution https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinx%2B2sin2x-sin3x-3%3D0. Also for all values of x the inequation you have written is greater than -3. But thats not a solution.

Comment: Of course there is no solution, I think I have explained it well.

Comment: When the equality is satisfied, $\sin x$ has to be 1, but that is not a solution, thus there is no solution.

Comment: The maximum value of $(2\cos x-1)^2-3$ is $6$. We are multiplying by $\sin x$ which could be negative. So I am not immediately clear why you rule out such solutions.

Comment: Not necessarily because even when sinx is less than 1 there might be valus of x when the term $4cos^2x-4cosx-2$ would be greater than -3 and thus this multiplied by sinx might give a solution. Proving that $4cos^2x-4cosx-2 \ge -3$ shows that there is a possibility of existence of a solution.

Comment: I have said on $(0,\pi)$, $\sin x>0$

Comment: Yes, the proof works for $0\le x\le\pi$. But what about $-\pi<x<0$?

Comment: @almagest You can work on that part but the question only asks about $(0,\pi)$

Comment: @Fan. Oh, you're right. I had not noticed that. Odd, since the relation is true for all $x$. Incidentally, I did not downvote you. But I guess I should now upvote! +1

Answer (score 2):

Here $$\sin x-\sin 3x+2\sin 2x = -2\cos(2x)\sin x+2\sin 2x\leq |2\cos 2x\sin x+2\sin 2x|$$

So $$\sin x-\sin 3x+2\sin 2x\leq 2|\sin 2x+\cos 2x|\leq 2\sqrt{2}|\sin (2x+45^\circ)|\leq 2\sqrt{2}<3$$

So no solution in $x\in (0,\pi)$